# Deploying a .NET core 2 website on a windows 2008 R2 server

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm currently working on a site project and I'm using .NET Core 2.
When I run my project locally everything works fine.
When I publish my site on the servers and I look in the publication folder I have the files. However when I call the URL of my site I have an error "HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure".
I read a lot of doc at the server configuration and this side everything seems ok. I think the concern comes from the config of my project, but I do not know too much or.
So if anyone has ever had this type of problem and if so, if there is a solution. I specify that I installed the core .NET bundle for Windows server.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Did you restart the server after installing the hosting bundle?

Comment: Also, open a command prompt in the directory where the app files are and run `dotnet Your.App.dll`. Ensure that it starts up without error. If there are errors, fix those.

Answer (score 3):

For me this is usually one of two things. You forgot to build the app with `.UseIISIntegration` in `Program.cs`, or it's missing dependencies.

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .Build();
```

If it's a dependency issue, you can be specific and define the platform you're publishing to in your `.csproj`, or you can just install the full SDK on the server. I typically go with the later because it makes my deploys smaller and I know I won't be missing something defined in the manifest.